# no match for call to ‘(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)'

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to make a simple server - client construction with boost asio (version 1.67).

When trying a acceptor sequence for the server it throws the following error:

```
no match for call to ‘(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket {aka boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>}) ()’
```

The code that the error is given on:

```
acceptor.async_accept(handler->socket (), [=](auto ec) {
        handle_new_connection(handler, ec);
    });
```

and the full function:

```
void start_server(uint16_t port){
    auto handler = std::make_shared<ConnectionHandler>(io_service);

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port);
    acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
    acceptor.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    acceptor.bind(endpoint);
    acceptor.listen();

    acceptor.async_accept(handler->socket (), [=](auto ec) {
        handle_new_connection(handler, ec);
    });

    for(int i = 0; i < thread_count; ++i){
        thread_pool.emplace_back([=]{
            io_service.run();
        });
    }
}
```

The connection handler as implemented:

```
template <typename ConnectionHandler>
class ServerMain {

using shared_handler_t = std::shared_ptr<ConnectionHandler>;

public:
ServerMain(int aThread_count=1): thread_count(aThread_count)
acceptor(io_service){

}
```

I watched the tutorial from CppCon, in which Michael Caisse explained how to make this server client connection.

The link at the correct timestamp: [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/rwOv_tw2eA4?t=2049)

Does this error have something to do with the boost version that I'm using?

Comment: I don't know these classes, but I guess it'd be useful to see ConnectionHandler, and at least the signature for its socket() method.

Comment: Since the class is made of a template, the name ConnectionHandler is a typename for ServerMain. I also added my source where I was getting my information from.

Comment: OK: you still haven't shown us socket, which I guess is on ServerMain now (which you haven't shown us). You can see Michael's chat_handler at 41:25, where `socket()` is an accessor that returns a reference to a socket object. I'm guessing your socket is just a member variable that you're reading directly i.e. not through an accessor? Then you just want `handler->socket` not `handler->socket()`.

Comment: What is `handler->socket`?